# How to create error ellipse for location uncertainty using an GeospatialPose or Pose of AR anchor?

Tags: android, statistics, geospatial, arcore, ellipse

I am trying to understand how can I create an error ellipse (semi-major and semi-minor axes) for location uncertainty.

I am working on **Google ARCore with Geospatial API** and when an anchor is placed, it has a **[Pose](https://developers.google.com/ar/reference/java/com/google/ar/core/Pose?hl=en)** which can then be converted into **[GeospatialPose](https://developers.google.com/ar/reference/java/com/google/ar/core/GeospatialPose?hl=en)**. These objects have some inbuilt functions to get the accuracy values (horizontal, vertical, orientation yaw). Pose object also has functions to extract translation matrix and orientation quaternion.

How do I use this information to get semi-major and semi-minor axes for the error ellipse?

Some sources mention that a covariance matrix has to be created for a 2D ellipse. I am not sure which info from the above can I use to create it if at all required.